# Why \z for regular expression doesn't work for me?

Tags: java, regex

I read in the Oracle documentary that `\z` means end of the input. But the compilator throws errors. 
I need to find a word "java" in text when java is the last word. Any sugestion how to deal with it?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Why {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String language = "java";
        String text = "I'm fan of java";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s" + language + "[\\W|\\z]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        System.out.println(m.find());  // <-------------- Exception 

    }

}

// Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
//                Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 11 \sjava[\W|\z]
```

Comment: It's a boundary matcher. You can't use it in a character class. Did you mean `(\\W|\\z)`?

Comment: Zero-width assertions do not preserve their meaning in character classes. Use `(?:\\W|\\z)`, or just `(?!\\w)`. You seem to be looking to match some word as a whole word, check if a mere `\b` word boundary works for you. If `language` may start/end with a non-word char, then `\b` won't work. You might use `"(?<!\\w)" + Pattern.quote(language) + "(?!\\w)"` then.

Comment: `[..]` represents character class (single one from specified range). `\z` doesn't represent character, but *place*, just like `\b` which also is not valid element for character class. BTW `|` in `[..]` is simple character, not OR operator.

Comment: thx all. :) Problem solved.

Comment: And how did you solve it?

Comment: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\s|\\A)" + language + "(\\W|\\z|\\d)");`

Comment: You may use `"(?<!\\S)" + Pattern.quote(language) + "(?![^\\W\\d])"` I guess.

Answer (score 2):

The `[...]` defines a character class, and you can define *chars* in there. `\z` is an anchor, a *zero-width assertion*. All zero-width assertions - `\A`, `\b`, `\G`, `^`, `$` - do not preserve their "special" meaning when put inside character classes.

The error you get is due to [the fact that](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

> It is an error to use a backslash prior to any alphabetic character that does not denote an escaped construct; these are reserved for future extensions to the regular-expression language.

You seem to want to match a word that has a whitespace or start of a string before or a non-word, a digit or end of string after. I suggest using

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\S)" + Pattern.quote(language) + "(?![^\\W\\d])");
```

The `(?<!\\S)` is a negative lookbehind that only matches a position that is immediately preceded with a whitespace or start of string. The `(?![^\\W\\d])` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if the next char is not a non-word char or not a digit (so there can be a digit, a non-word or end of string).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AQ7lEr/1).

Comment: The negative lookarounds look cryptic, but they are much more efficient than alternations, especially in Java regex. Just to clarify further: `(?<!\S)` = `(?<=\s|^)`,  `[^\W\d]` = *any letter or `_`*, `[\w&&[^\d]]`, and `(?![^\W\d])` =  `(?=\W|\d|$)`