# What's wrong with this regex """[\b]""".r in scala

Tags: scala

It throws this error:

```
scala> val a = """[\b]""".r
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 2
```

According to https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/util/matching/Regex.html, backslashes don't need to be escaped when using the triple quotes. When I try the same with \n, \t, \v, it does not give me an error. The \b is special in the sense that it has a different meaning when inside brackets (where it is a backspace char) vs. matching word boundaries.

Comment: You may want to refer to "[Why \z for regular expression doesn't work for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46352041/234658)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\b` is not getting interpreted as a backspace character. `"""[\b]"""` is equivalent to `"[\\b]"`. The reason backslashes don't need to be escaped when using the triple quotes is that backslashes don't have any special significance, because escape sequences are not supported at all. So there is no way to type a backspace character in this form of string expression.

To use an escape sequence, such as `\b` to represent backspace, you need to use the traditional quotation style:

```
scala> val a = "[\b]".r
a: scala.util.matching.Regex = [?]
```

Unfortunately, you *will* now have to escape any other backslashes that may be present in your regular expression.